# Dictionary error: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the frequency from a list. I received an type error

```
mylist = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
def frequency(x):
    counts = dict()
    if x in counts:
        counts[x] += 1
    elif len(counts) < 3:
        counts.update([x, 1])            
    return counts
```

```
for x in mylist:
    frequency(x)
```

I received `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence` on `counts.update([x, 1])`. I checked what this error is about, but I cannot see I violated it.

Comment: Why not just use a `Counter`?

Comment: Incidentally, your code is wrong because it creates a new `count` each time `frequency` is called, which is then discarded when you `return` it but don't assign it to a value in the loop. Basically, as is, your code does nothing (besides throwing an error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix

The `counts` should be created **outside**, so before, if you create it in the method, that will be new one each time

You may update a dict with another dict, not a list

```
counts.update({x: 1})
```

---

#### Improve logic

- simply do `counts[x] = 1` instead, that's cheaper
- it woul be better that the method does the whole frequency computation, from a list

```py
counts = {}
def frequency(values):
    for x in values:
        if x in counts:
            counts[x] += 1
        else:
            counts[x] = 1
    return counts

mylist = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
counts = frequency(mylist)
print(counts)  # {1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1}
```

---

#### Improve code

There is method that could help you get nicer code

- `collections.defaultdict` that handles if the key isn't present (set 0, as we told him `int`)

  ```py
  def frequency(values):
      counts = defaultdict(int)
      for x in values:
          counts[x] += 1
      return counts
  ```
- the master of all `collections.Counter`

  ```py
  def frequency(values):
      return Counter(values)
  ```